# how to get the ID of a sub collection in Firestore HTML?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a collection name ("users") and inside it i have created subCollection("innerGuides"). I know how to retrieve data from the main collection ("users"), but i want to know how can i get the ID of my subCollection("innerGuides").

```
db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).collection("innerGuides").doc("BGP9O0Rh2ThiL40tXOVG").get().then(doc => {
    console.log(user.uid);
    console.log(doc.data().content);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

as you can see i can retrieve my main collection UID through "user.uid" but for my subCollection how can i retrieve its "uid". I have typed the subCollection uid, but how to retrieve it dynamically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the id of a [DocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot) is, from your example:

```js
db.collection("users").doc(user.uid).collection("innerGuides").doc("BGP9O0Rh2ThiL40tXOVG").get().then(doc => {
    console.log(doc.id);  // <-- here
    console.log(doc.data().content);
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  })
```

You can also use `doc.exists` to see if the document your `get()` actually exists.

To see your document, with id, something like:

```js
console.log({
  id: doc.id,
  ...doc.data(),
});
```

The id of the sub-collection something like: `users/the-user-id/innerGuides/BGP9O0Rh2ThiL40tXOVG`. There is no way to only return `BGP9O0Rh2ThiL40tXOVG`, as by itself it isn't a complete reference. If you need that value parse it out of the id. JavaScript has many ways to do that. One off the top of my head is split():

```js
const subId = id.split('/')[3]
```

Probably best to validate the array first, etc., but it will get you the id when successful.

Comment: your answer is somewhat correct but i want to retrieve the data from my subCollection as you can see i have a reference const to main collection ID ("user.uid") but how can i create a ref to my subCollection ID

Comment: Isn’t `BGP9O0Rh2ThiL40tXOVG` your sub-collection id in your example? Perhaps I am not understanding what you are trying to do.

Comment: yup you are right..... 'BGP9O0Rh2ThiL40tXOVG' is my subCollection ID but as you see i have typed the ID by myself but i want to store this ID to a const...  how to do that ?

Comment: For clarification, the current id looks somethking like `users/the-user-id/innerGuides/BGP9O0Rh2ThiL40tXOVG`?